# How to return early without return statement?

Tags: scala, functional-programming, return

How to write an early-return piece of code in scala with no returns/breaks?

For example

```
for i in 0..10000000
  if expensive_operation(i)
     return i
return -1
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you asked for intuition to solve this problem generically. Let me start from the basis.

**Scala** is *(between other things)* a functional programming language, as such there is a very important concept for us. And it is that we write programs by composing `expressions` rather than `statements`.

Thus, the concept of return value for us means the evaluation of an `expression`.
*(Note this is related to the concept of **referential transparency**)*.

```
val a = expr   // a is bounded to the evaluation of expr,
val b = (a, a) // and they are interchangeable, thus b === (expr, expr)
```

How this relates to your question. In the sense that we really do not have control structures but complex expressions. For example an `if`

```
val a = if (expr) exprA else exprB // if itself is an expression, that returns other expressions.
```

Thus instead of doing something like this:

```
def foo(a: Int): Int =
  if (a != 0) {
    val b = a * a
    return b
  }
  return -1
```

We would do something like:

```
def foo(a: Int): Int =
  if (a != 0)
    a * a
  else
   -1
```

Because we can bound all the `if` expression itself as the body of foo.

---

Now, returning to your specific question. How can we early return a `cycle`?
The answer is, you can't, at least not without mutations. But, you can use a higher concept, instead of **iterating**, you can **traverse** something. And you can do that using `recursion`.

Thus, let's implement ourselves the `find` proposed by @Thilo, as a `tail-recursive` function.
*(It is very important that the function is recursive by tail, so the compiler optimizes it as something equivalent to a while loop, that way we will not blow up the stack)*.

```
def find(start: Int, end: Int, step: Int = 1)(predicate: Int => Boolean): Option[Int] = {
  @annotation.tailrec
  def loop(current: Int): Option[Int] =
    if (current == end)
      None // Base case.
    else if (predicate(current))
      Some(current) // Early return.
    else
      loop(current + step) // Recursive step.
  loop(current = start)
}

find(0, 10000)(_ == 10)
// res: Option[Int] = Some(10)
```

Or we may generalize this a little bit more, let's implement find for **Lists** of any kind of elements.

```
def find[T](list: List[T])(predicate: T => Boolean): Option[T] = {
  @annotation.tailrec
  def loop(remaining: List[T]): Option[T] =
    remaining match {
      case Nil                      => None
      case t :: _ if (predicate(t)) => Some(t)
      case _ :: tail                => loop(remaining = tail)
    }
  loop(remaining = list)
}
```

Comment: The only thing I can think of that it is maybe too much - more than the question was about. But anyway 1plus from me for this excellent explanation;).

Comment: @pme Thanks, I still fail too see how explaining more is _"bad"_ _(I can think on a few reasons but I do not believe they apply to this)_. But in any case, I wrote all this due this [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58134049/how-to-avoid-early-returns-in-scala/58136084#comment102655618_58134108) where OP ask not for a solution for this particular scenario, but to the problem in general.

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez In what way is _traversal_ different from _iteration_? Is the difference in not having to keep track of index in traversal?

Comment: @MarioGalic Iterate mean "going one by one in an order", traversal just mean "pass through the structure", it is a more general term, all iterations are traversal, but not the oposite. For example a **map** is a traversal _(that for most types it is implemented with an iteration)_. The best example I know is a tree, a traversal may be just a recursive algorithm, whereas an iteration would require to build a list of nodes in some order. _(Note usually one ends up creating some kind of iteration for efficiency, for example a tail-recursive BFS / DFS)_.

Answer (score 10):

How about

```
 input.find(expensiveOperation).getOrElse(-1)
```

Comment: always when you think you have the simplest solution there is a simpler one in Scala;)

Answer (score 5):

You can use `dropWhile`

Here an example:

```
Seq(2,6,8,3,5).dropWhile(_ % 2 == 0).headOption.getOrElse(default = -1) // -> 8
```

And here you find more [scala-takewhile-example](http://allaboutscala.com/tutorials/chapter-8-beginner-tutorial-using-scala-collection-functions/scala-takewhile-example/)

With your example

```
(0 to 10000000).dropWhile(!expensive_operation(_)).headOption.getOrElse(default = -1)`
```

Comment: Since OP asked for the value or a `-1` it would be better to `dropWhile(x => !expensiveOperation(x)).headOption.getOrElse(default = -1)`. - Additionally `last` is a very expensive and unsafe operation.

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez I agree with `-1` but he also wants the last element. So would you suggest to rather make a `reverse` and then take the `head`?

Comment: Please take my example as something just hinting at a generic situation in which you might want to return early since it is very expensive to do something on all elements of a collection, and you might return a default value in case nothing worked out.

Comment: @pme No, just `dropWhile` instead of `takeWhile` and `headOption` instead of `last`.

Comment: @MichelePiccolini sadly this is not as generic, as the new answer suggest, you can also use `find` or `collectFirst` or `iterator + filter + headOption`. There are many ways to accomplish this in **Scala**. You will be learning about them. What is general is to forget about iteration, and think about a traversal, implementing the solution by hand, using a _tail-recursive_ algorithm over **List** helps to understand.

Answer (score 2):

This is not necessarily the best solution from a practical perspective but I still wanted to add it for educational purposes:

```
import scala.annotation.tailrec

def expensiveOperation(i: Int): Boolean = ???

@tailrec
def findFirstBy[T](f: (T) => Boolean)(xs: Seq[T]): Option[T] = {
   xs match {
       case Seq() => None
       case Seq(head, _*) if f(head) => Some(head)
       case Seq(_, tail@_*) => findFirstBy(f)(tail)
   }
}

val result = findFirstBy(expensiveOperation)(Range(0, 10000000)).getOrElse(-1)
```

Please prefer collections methods (`dropWhile`, `find`, ...) in your production code.

Answer (score 1):

There a lot of better answer here but I think a 'while' could work just fine in that situation.

So, this code

```
for i in 0..10000000
  if expensive_operation(i)
     return i
return -1
```

could be rewritten as

```
var i = 0
var result = false
while(!result && i<(10000000-1)) {
    i = i+1
    result = expensive_operation(i)
}
```

After the 'while' the variable 'result' will tell if it succeed or not.